# Swift generics and CMutableVoidPointer

Tags: generics, swift, nsdata

I have the following function at the moment in my generic class

```
func writeHeader(buffer: CMutableVoidPointer) {

    var headerData = NSData(bytesNoCopy:buffer, length:sizeof(H))
    self.fileHandle.writeData(headerData)
}
```

But as you see this is not very type safe. I tried this but it does not compile

```
func writeHeader(buffer: CMutablePointer<H>) {

    var headerData = NSData(bytesNoCopy:buffer, length:sizeof(H))
    self.fileHandle.writeData(headerData)
}
```

Any idea?

UPDATE

This is part of a generic class as mentioned in the first sentence, sorry next time im more specific.

```
class DataStore<H> { 
     .....
}
```

Comment: Is `H` an actual type?

Comment: It doesn't compile because you can't provide half-types to the compiler.  You need to indicate that H should be deduced by placing it in some angle brackets: `func writeHeader<H>(buffer: CMutablePointer<H>)`

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Is `buffer` a property of `DataStore` or something else? How would `writeHeader` be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
func writeHeader<H>(buffer: CConstPointer<H>) {

    let headerData = buffer.withUnsafePointer {
       NSData(bytesNoCopy: $0, length: sizeof(H), freeWhenDone: false)
    }
    self.fileHandle.writeData(headerData)
}
```