# Struct into NSData

Tags: swift, nsdata

This is quite clear and works:

```
struct DEMO {
   var used: Bool = false;
}

var a = DEMO()
var dataA = NSData(bytesNoCopy: &a, length: sizeof(DEMO))
```

This make sense because this method uses a CMutableVoidPointer.

Now use a const:

```
let b = DEMO(used:true)
var dataC = NSData(bytes: &b, length: sizeof(DEMO)) // ERROR
var dataB = NSData(bytesNoCopy: &b, length: sizeof(DEMO))  // ERROR
```

And you get an error on both init methodes, but why?

Do I really have to copy first a const into a var to use it?

```
var c = b
var dataC = NSData(bytes: &c, length: sizeof(DEMO))
```

I think this is why it is a similar problem within a function, you get a "let":

```
func test(data: DEMO) {
  var c = NSData(bytes: data, length: sizeof(DEMO)) // ERROR
  var b = NSData(bytes: &data, length: sizeof(DEMO)) // ERROR
  var d = NSData(bytesNoCopy: data, length: sizeof(DEMO)) // ERROR
  var a = NSData(bytesNoCopy: &data, length: sizeof(DEMO)) // ERROR
}
```

All of them deliver errors.

How to handle swift const with NSData?

Comment: I assume that you just cannot take the address of a Swift constant (but I do not have a definite reference). - Note that you should not use the "no copy" variant, because in that case the NSData object calls free() on the memory buffer on deallocation. That is also what I experienced here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24471017/1187415. With `NSData(bytesNoCopy ...)` you get an "invalid free" as soon as the NSData object goes out of scope.

Comment: Well the "invalid free" should be handable by `NSData(bytesNoCopy: &data, length: sizeof(DEMO),freeWhenDone:false)` right?

Comment: Yes, you are completely right.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Martin R comment I suggest a "work around" solution for the function part

```
func test(inout data: DEMO) {
  var a = NSData(bytesNoCopy: &data, length: sizeof(DEMO),freeWhenDone:false)

  .... 
}
```

The inout parameter provide at least a not cost version of data.

Comment: But `let b = DEMO(used:true) ; test(&b)` still does not work. So at *some point* you have to make a "var" copy of the constant.

Comment: yes this is correct but without inout you have to make a var copy all the time indepdende if you use outside a var or a const.